# Why haven't I gotten my head?

Tags: borderlands-2

Gearbox is offering [SHIFT codes](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1074/borderlands-2-dragon-keep-heads-shift-codes) that unlock character heads based on Tiny Tina's DLC.  I own the game through Steam and the DLC through the Season Pass (also Steam).

The Gearbox page says:

> Look for these customizations to appear in Dice Chests in-game (more on that here) or click on each image above for a SHiFT code to **unlock the head for that character immediately** -- new images and codes will be posted daily through Sunday, August 18!!

However, I've used the code for both Gaige and Axton but the head has not shown up in my Quick Change machines (nor my inventory).  They do show up on my list of unlocked content.  Is this a bug or do codes just make the items drop in-game?

Comment: Do you have a Shift account?

Comment: I would assume so.  I've redeemed SHIFT keys and they ended up in the game.  I'll have to check later.

Comment: Shift was having some problems https://twitter.com/SHiFTstatus/status/367002399317032960 They said that they fixed it https://twitter.com/SHiFTstatus/status/367002399317032960 but if you are experiencing issues, they recommend you contact http://support.gearboxsoftware.com

Comment: @skovacs1 you should make that an answer.

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 Sure, although this question may be a candidate for closure as being too localized in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHiFT was [having some problems](http://twitter.com/SHiFTstatus/status/367002399317032960). They said [that they had fixed it](http://twitter.com/SHiFTstatus/status/367002399317032960), but if you are experiencing issues, they recommended you contact [support.gearboxsoftware.com](http://support.gearboxsoftware.com).

In general, when Shift is not behaving, you should always first check out [their twitter](https://twitter.com/SHiFTstatus) or [Gearbox's twitter](https://twitter.com/GearboxSoftware) as they usually re-tweet @SHiFTstatus. For support on SHiFT issues, contact [support.gearboxsoftware.com](http://support.gearboxsoftware.com).